# Get last instance of counted rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, count, greatest-n-per-group

There are two tables `jobs` and `users`. `users` has a 1-to-many relation to `jobs`.

I want to grab the email of all users who have done 5 or more jobs.

The query below does that. However, how can I also retrieve the date of the last job done by the user.
So the desired output would be:

```
Email          jobs done    date of last of job
jack@email.com   5+         1-20-2015  
joe@email.com    5+         2-20-2015
```

**Query that grabs all emails of users who have done 5+ jobs**

```
select
 email
 , case
 when times_used >= 5
  then '5+'
end as times_used
from
(
  select
  u.id
  , u.email as email
  , count(*) as times_used

from
  jobs j
  join users u on
    j.user_id = u.id
group by
  u.id
)
 a
  where
   times_used >= 5
   group by
    times_used
   , email
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a join for another derived table that pulls the last date for each user:

```
select
    b.email, 
    case when times_used >= 5  then '5+' end as 'jobs done',
    b.max_date 'date of last job'
from (
    select u.id, count(*) as times_used
    from jobs j 
    join users u on j.user_id = u.id
    group by u.id
) a
join ( 
    select u.id, u.email, max(j.date) max_date 
    from jobs j
    join users u on j.user_id = u.id 
    group by u.id, email
) b on b.id = a.id 
where times_used >= 5
```

But if you only want the email, number of jobs and date of the last job for all users that have 5+ jobs then you the query below should be enough:

```
select u.id, u.email, max(j.date) max_date 
from jobs j
join users u on j.user_id = u.id 
group by u.id, u.email
having count(j.id) >= 5
```

Both queries assume that the `jobs` table looks like `id (pk), user_id, date` so you have to adjust according to your actual table definition.

Comment: yep both suggestions are spot on. I do need other segmentations than 5+ in the end so the first is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `WINDOW` function approach, as it can be more efficient:

```
WITH user_jobs AS (
SELECT 
 u.id as user_id,
 j.id as job_id,
 u.email,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY j.date DESC) as rn,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY j.date) as job_number
FROM 
 jobs j
 join users u ON j.user_id = u.id
)
SELECT 
  user_id,
  job_id,
  email,
  job_number
FROM user_jobs
WHERE rn = 1 and job_number >= 5
```